# Creating string vector from loop

Tags: string, r, for-loop

I am trying to create a label to the `combn` command so that I know exactly which pairs where compared.
Here's an example:
Let a be my vector of interest,

```
a<-seq(1,10,1)
c<-combn(a,2)
```

So I want to create a vector *label* with the numbers that are paired:

```
label<-rep("abc",times=ncol(c)) #This is just a vector to initialized "label"
head(label)

for(i in ncol(c)){
label[i]<-c(paste("Exon",c[1,i],"with",c[2,i]))
}
head(label)
```

The problem is when I run the `for` loop it doesn't work. Alternatively, it only outputs the last comparison.

Comment: Your loop runs only once because `ncol(c)` is only a single value. You have to use something like `1:ncol(c)` or `seq(along=label)`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the loop and use a vectorized approach:

```
label <- paste("Exon", c[1,] "with", c[2,])
```

BTW: `c` is a very bad variable name (see `?c`).

Comment: @sgibb why is very bad to use `c` as a name? you should (some situations) use `base::c` , that's about it. maybe not elegant but I don't think it is so bad.